# Reading item in PHP Multi Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I would like to read the following JSON info in PHP using a foreach. Im new to this and need some help. I have only included a small sample of the data for privacy reasons.

The end goal is to get all the "id" and the "real_address" in the server array.

```
[
   {
      "id":"d87df8g7sdfg89",
      "status":false,
      "servers":[
         {
            "status":false,
            "platform":null,
            "server_id":"adsfasdfasdfasdf",
            "virt_address6":"fd00:c0a8:f800:0:192:168:248:5",
            "virt_address":"192.168.248.5",
            "name":"Private",
            "real_address":null,
            "connected_since":null,
            "id":"aasdfasdfasdfsafde",
            "device_name":null
         }
      ],
   },
   {
      "id":"asd89asd8f",
      "status":true,
      "servers":[
         {
            "status":true,
            "platform":"linux",
            "server_id":"fasdsdfasdfasdf",
            "virt_address6":"fd00:c0a8:f800:0:192:168:248:3",
            "virt_address":"192.168.248.3",
            "name":"Private",
            "real_address":"5.5.5.52",
            "connected_since":1447406908,
            "id":"asdfasdfasdfasdf",
            "device_name":"thriving-fields-2667"
         }
      ],
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json_decode`

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($data as $value) {
    foreach ($value['servers'] as $server) {
        echo $server['real_address'];
    }
}
```

Comment: This was perfect but I forgot to add I needed the ID as well. I updated the sample data in my original request

Comment: You can get the id using $server['id];

Comment: Had to use $value[id] because it was not in the servers array. But it got me on the right path. Thank you Pierre for the help.

Answer (score 0):

something like this ...

```
$items = json_decode($json);
foreach($items as $item){
    foreach($item->servers as $server)
    {
        echo $server->server_id . " - ". $server->status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP >= 5.5.0 for `array_column()` you can try this:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach (array_column($array, 'servers') as $server) {   
    echo $server['real_address'];
}
```